# Equation simplification in Maxima

Tags: maxima

I have the following expression:

```
(x^2*α^2*(α/β)^m*β^m-x^2*α^(m+2))/(2*β^2)
```

I think the numerator should simplify to zero, but I can't seem to get Maxima to do so.

Comment: Looks like `radcan(foo)` reduces the expression (denoted `foo` here) to 0. Try also `declare(m, integer)` and then `expand(foo, 0, 0)` (note that `expand(something, 0, 0)` is a conventional way to resimplify an expression).

Comment: Glad to help. Aside from this forum, you can try the Maxima mailing list. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss